# The meaning of product of functions in multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

If $f$ and $g$ are $2$ functions $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$

For $m=1$ and $n>1$ is $f\cdot g$ or $(f\cdot g)(x)$ defined for? Would that be a real number? And for $n=1$ and $m>1$, is $f\cdot g$ defined?

Comment: I don't get if you mean scalar product ($f(x) \cdot g(x)$) or compound function ($f(g(x))$.

Comment: Multiplication.is that called also scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m=1$ and any $n \geq 1$, we can consider the function $f \cdot g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ defined by

$$x \mapsto f(x)g(x).$$

For $n=1$ and $m>1$, there isn't as obvious a way to define multiplication of functions. Trying to mimic the case for $n=1$, we would want to define $f\cdot g: \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R^n$ by "multiplying the resulting vectors". One way to do this would be to use the dot product. Suppose that $f$ is given in components by

$$a \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} f_1(a) \\ \vdots \\ f_m(a)\end{pmatrix}$$ and $g$ is given in components by

$$a \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} g_1(a) \\ \vdots \\ g_m(a)\end{pmatrix}.$$ That is, each $f_i$ and $g_i$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Then the function $f\cdot g: \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R^m$ defined by

$$a \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} f_1(a) \\ \vdots \\ f_m(a)\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} g_1(a) \\ \vdots \\ g_m(a)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} f_1(a)g_1(a) \\ \vdots \\ f_m(a)g_m(a)\end{pmatrix}$$ makes sense.

As an aside, we can in fact define this dot product of functions for *any* $n,m > 0$, and in such a way that the general dot product agrees with the two special cases discussed above when $n=1$ or $m=1$.

Comment: In the last sentence when you write n,m>=0 you mean the the general case of the dot product of $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$? @Morgan

Comment: Thank you your question and attention

Comment: @user289460 Give $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ and $g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, for any $n,m> 0$ we can define a function from $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ by $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \mapsto f(a_1,\dots,a_n)\cdot g(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. Note that $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $g(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^m$, so it makes sense to take their dot product. Hope this helps, and you're welcome!

Comment: @user289460 I realize that, in my original answer, I said $n,m \geq 0$. While you can make sense of this for $n=0$, it's probably best to assume $n,m>0$.